C++: Error using rename function with LPCSTR and char *
It is my first time coding in C++, and I'm doing a little project for the company I'm doing my internship at with a library that I've never tried before.
The objective of this project is to scan the QR code that is stored in the path and then add whatever the QR code equals to + '__' + old name, or "NOQR_" + old name in a different folder. The code I have so far is the following:
void move_original(const char* file, const char* read)
{
    std::string dir_path = "C:\\testing\\originals\\";
    std::string file_str = file;
    std::string read_str = read;

    size_t last_backslash_pos = file_str.find_last_of('\\');
    if (last_backslash_pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        // Extract the directory path
        std::string file_name = file_str.substr(last_backslash_pos + 1);

        // Create the new file name
        std::string new_file_name = dir_path + read_str + '_' + file_name;

        std::cout << file;
        std::cout << new_file_name;

               if (std::rename(file, new_file_name.c_str()) != 0) {
                   std::cout << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
                   return; // Return early to indicate failure
               }

               // File moved successfully
               std::cout << "File moved successfully" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Invalid file path" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    void* pReader = SDTCreateBarcodeReaderA("License");

    if (pReader)
    {
        SDTSetReadInputTypes(pReader, SDTBARCODETYPE_QRCODE);
        const char* file_name = "C:\\testing\\input\\test2.png";

        SDTReadImageFileA(pReader, file_name, 0);
        if (SDTGetResultsCount(pReader) > 0)
        {
            LPCSTR value = SDTGetResultValueA(pReader, 0);
            // std::cout << "Found Barcode: " << value << " \n";
            const char* read = value;
            move_original(file_name, read);
        }
        else
        {
            move_original(file_name, "NOQR");
        }

        if (pReader)
        {
            SDTDestroyBarcodeReader(pReader);
            pReader = NULL;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

I have tried adding a file that doesn't have a QR code and my "move_original" function works correctly, so I'm assuming this has something to do with the LPCSTR to char * conversion which I know absolutely nothing at all, but when printed on console the name looks fine so I'm kind of lost now.
Output of the console is:

C:\testing\input\test2.png


C:\testing\originals\990**************9_test2.png


Error: Invalid argument

Let me know if you need more information, I'm using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10.

LPCSTR value = SDTGetResultValueA(pReader, 0); --> std::string value = SDTGetResultValueA(pReader, 0);.  Just because the function says it returns a LPCSTR doesn't mean you need to be using the return value as an LPCSTR forever.  If the function returns a null-terminated character buffer, that's all that is needed to create an actual std::string from the return value.

LPCSTR to const char* conversion is a no-op. These are the same type

Another possibility is that Windows does not like a * in a file name. Just speculating.

Having done a tiny amount of research, I think the problem is the * character in the second file name, that's not allowed in Windows.

Rules for file names on Windows are here. Asterisks are not allowed.

ohh thank you! i was trying to test it before getting the license but it looks like ill have to do it anyway because otherwise they use '*' to cover the full name.

@seweeny or you can just put the original image and the output image in a temporary folder, then loop through the files in that folder looking for the new image ...
